# Does the Axiom of Choice imply the existence of all the choice functions of a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, axiom-of-choice

We know that, given a set $X$, there exists at least one choice function $f:X\rightarrow\cup X$ thanks to the Axiom of Choice (AC).

Can we conclude that all choice functions for a generic set $X$ exist?

Do we have any information regarding the cardinality of the set of choice functions?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it makes no sense to ask "[do] all choice functions [...] exist?". If a choice function exists, then it is included in the "all". If it does not exist, there is no sense in including "it" in the "all" (what even is "it"?) unless you're doing something spooky like working with a metatheory. The axiom of choice isn't saying that we are allowed to use certain things which exist, it's saying that these things exist in the first place

Comment: Wouldn't the cardinality of the set of choice functions be $\prod_{x\in X}|x|$? It is the cardinality of the product (which by definition is the set of all choice functions), which is the product of the cardinalities.

Comment: I believe that the cardinality of the set of choice functions is $\# ( \prod_{x\in X} x )$ independent of the axiom of choice; it's just that the axiom of choice is needed to prevent $\prod_{x\in X} x$ from being the empty set. I don't know how cardinal multiplication works in the absence of the axiom of choice; in particular, $\# ( \prod_{x\in X} x ) = ( \prod_{x\in X} \# x )$ doesn't seem automatic.

Comment: @GregMartin Cardinal multiplication isn't even well-defined in the absence of choice. E.g., $|\prod_{n<\omega}2| = 2^{\aleph_0}\ne 0,$ but we can have $(X_n: n< \omega)$ such that $|X_n|=2$ for all $n$ and $|\prod_{n< \omega} X_n | = 0.$

Comment: You don't need the axiom of choice to prove the existence of a function $f:X \to \cup X$. That is a consequence of the other axioms of ZF. Given any set $X$, ZF allows you to prove the existence of $\cup X$, and the existence of the set $Z=\{f: X \to \cup X\}$, and the existence of the set $C=\{f \in Z \mid f \text{ is a choice function}\}$. The existence of all those sets doesn't need the the axiom of choice. All the axiom of choice tells you is $C\ne \emptyset$.

Comment: (Should clarify what I wrote above... *infinite* products of cardinals aren't well-defined. Binary multiplication is fine.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To an extent, this question doesn't make any sense.

The existence of an object is measured against a fixed universe. Namely, either there is or there is *a* choice function to begin with. And a set is either finite or empty or infinite or uncountable, or anything, in a given context and a fixed universe.

The set of **all** choice functions ***always*** exists. It is a consequence of how we define a choice function, as well as the other axioms of set theory. The axiom of choice merely implies that this set is not empty.

What is true, however, is that if we have a single choice function, provided that the family is not a family of singletons, there will be other choice functions as well. Indeed, we can combine all sort of choice functions together, and we can do all kind of "crazy things" to show that if there are two choice functions we can define a third (provided the family is not just one pair and a bunch of singletons), etc. But, this has nothing to do with the axiom of choice and everything to do with the other axioms of set theory.

For example, suppose that $\{A_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a family of non-empty sets such that no infinitely many of them admit a choice function. And now consider $B_n=A_n\cup\{n\}$. Now $\{B_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ does admit a choice function, namely $n\mapsto n$. But we can also alter this choice function on finitely many coordinates to pick members of the $A_n$s instead of the integer. We have a more complicated situation if an infinite subfamily does admit a choice function, too. But this is not because of the axiom of choice, this is merely because *there exists a choice function* to begin with. In the general the axiom of choice merely allows us to make that initial step, wherein the journey towards this chaos begins (and in a very deep sense, a journey from a much bigger and more complicated chaos also takes place).

Comment: I'm happy to hear specific complaints about this, by the way.

Comment: From a naive perspective, I think that "all possible choice functions exist" means something along the lines of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1141051/is-there-a-strong-version-of-the-axiom-of-choice/1141100#1141100). At least, I think this formulation of the axiom of choice is the closest we can get to a faithful transcription of "all possible choice functions exist", without sacrificing mathematical rigour.

Comment: @Joe You could generalise your statement even farther to say that all partial choice functions can be extended to a total choice function. Given a partial choice function $f : Y \to \cup X$ where $Y \subseteq X$, we can pick a choice function $W \to \cup W$, where $W = X \setminus Y$. Then $W \cup Y$ extends $Y$ to a total choice function.